# Video editing - Changing Soundtrack

Tags: video

I have a short MP4 clip of my adult daughter being interviewed on television. I also have an MP3 sound clip of her talking aged 3 years.

What's the best way to substitute the sound on the video with the sound on the MP3 file using available Ubuntu software, please? It doesn't have to be exact.

(This is the sort of thing Dads do! ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Multiple YouTube videos on the subject found with this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=change+soundtrack+on+MP4+video+editor+linux

Multiple Linux video editor apps are listed at https://itsfoss.com/best-video-editing-software-linux/

A few reviews of those tools are at https://opensource.com/article/18/4/new-state-video-editing-linux

That article suggested converting the MP3 file to WAV first, easily done as described in https://linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_Convert_audio_files

If the audio clip is too short or long, [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) can alter its length without changing the pitch.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use Kdenlive, you can mute the origonal and set the new one under it. If the new clip is a bit too long, you can (in theory) speed it up a little without changing pitch (dont do that too much though, since generally that still makes ik sound different)